# Where does the term "marginal" in "marginal probability" or "marginal distribution" come from?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, terminology, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Where does the term "marginal" in "marginal probability" or "marginal distribution" come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article about [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution):

> These terms are dubbed "marginal" because they *used to be found by summing values in a table along rows or columns, and writing the sum in the margins of the table*.